# FFmpeg reported framerate changes when stream-copying

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I want to run three commands which introduce artificial "stalling" and audio pauses in a video file. They are the following – in this particular case, stalling should be introduced at seconds 0 and 5, for 2 seconds each:

`ffmpeg -nostdin -threads 1 -n -i P2LVL18_SRC20034_HRC1802_concat_wo_buffer.avi -filter_complex '[0:v]loop=loop=48:size=1:start=0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,loop=loop=48:size=1:start=168,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[stallvid];color=c=black:r=24.0[black];[black][stallvid]scale2ref[black2][stallvid];[stallvid][black2]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1:enable='"'"'between(t,0,1.99)'"'"'[stallvid2];[stallvid2]avgblur=5:enable='"'"'between(t,0,1.99)+between(t,7,8.99)'"'"',eq=brightness=0.0:enable='"'"'between(t,0,1.99)+between(t,7,8.99)'"'"'[stallvidblur];movie=filename=spinners/spinner-256-white.png:loop=0,setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)*2,fps=fps=24.0[spinner];[stallvidblur][spinner]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1:enable='"'"'between(t,0,1.99)+between(t,7,8.99)'"'"'[outv]' -map '[outv]' -c:v ffv1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync cfr buffered.avi_video.nut`

`ffmpeg -nostdin -threads 1 -n -i P2LVL18_SRC20034_HRC1802_concat_wo_buffer.avi -filter_complex '[0:a]aloop=loop=96000:size=1:start=0,asetpts=N/SAMPLE_RATE/TB,aloop=loop=96000:size=1:start=336000,asetpts=N/SAMPLE_RATE/TB,volume=0:enable='"'"'between(t,0,2)+between(t,7,9)'"'"'[outa]' -map '[outa]' -c:a pcm_s16le buffered.avi_audio.nut`

`ffmpeg -n -i buffered.avi_video.nut -i buffered.avi_audio.nut -c copy buffered.avi`

Processing audio and video at the same time hasn't worked well for me in the past, and the video stream must be kept separate too, hence the separate processing.

In the last step, the video and audio streams are "just" copied, but I'm observing that the reported FPS changes, effectively doubling the frame rate.

Here's the log from processing the video:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.5.0 (Homebrew gcc 5.5.0_4)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3-with-options --enable-shared --enable-hardcoded-tables --cc=gcc-5 --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --disable-htmlpages --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'P2LVL18_SRC20034_HRC1802_concat_wo_buffer.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
  Duration: 00:02:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 83129 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), yuv420p, 2560x1440, 81613 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (ffv1) -> loop
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (ffv1)
Output #0, nut, to 'buffered.avi_video.nut':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), yuv420p, 2560x1440 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 24 fps, 49152 tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 ffv1
frame= 2976 fps= 13 q=-0.0 Lsize= 1740152kB time=00:02:03.95 bitrate=115000.9kbits/s speed=0.551x    
video:1740055kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.005601%
```

Here's the log from the audio processing (banner truncated):

```
Input #0, avi, from 'P2LVL18_SRC20034_HRC1802_concat_wo_buffer.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
  Duration: 00:02:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 83129 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), yuv420p, 2560x1440, 81613 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s16le) -> aloop
  volume -> Stream #0:0 (pcm_s16le)
Output #0, nut, to 'buffered.avi_audio.nut':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le (PSD[16] / 0x10445350), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 pcm_s16le
size=   23477kB time=00:02:03.95 bitrate=1551.6kbits/s speed= 100x    
video:0kB audio:23241kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.016329%
```

And here's the log from copying:

```
Input #0, nut, from 'buffered.avi_video.nut':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:02:03.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 115000 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), yuv420p, 2560x1440, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 49152 tbn, 49152 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 ffv1
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, nut, from 'buffered.avi_audio.nut':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:02:03.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1551 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le (PSD[16] / 0x10445350), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 pcm_s16le
Output #0, avi, to 'buffered.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), yuv420p, 2560x1440 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 48 tbn, 48 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 ffv1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 pcm_s16le
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 2976 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1769610kB time=00:02:03.97 bitrate=116928.1kbits/s speed= 136x    
video:1740055kB audio:23241kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.358131%
```

I notice that `tbc` from the video file has changed from 24 to 49152, and that in the output, the `tbn` and `tbc` values are now set to 48.

When I read the file again, the `fps` change to 48:

```
Input #0, avi, from 'buffered.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:02:04.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 116908 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), yuv420p, 2560x1440, 114994 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 48 fps, 48 tbr, 48 tbn, 48 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
```

The file `buffered.avi` shows `nb_frames=5952`, while the original has `nb_frames=2880` when inspected with `ffprobe`.

When I run the actual frame count with `ffprobe`'s `count_frames`, I get 2976 for `buffered.avi`, and 2880 for the original. The difference, 96, is exactly 4 × 24 frames worth of stalling.

Why is that mismatch in the container, and what can I do to avoid the "frame duplication"?

The input file has a constant frame rate with regular PTS increments at 1/24th of a second.

What I've tried:

- Using MKV as intermediate container
- Removing all the extra loop processing from the video command

Comment: Quick check: use mkv instead of nut.

Comment: Tried that, same issue. The video MKV has 1k tbn and tbc, but when stream-copying to the output AVI, it again incorrectly has wrong fps.

Comment: Is the input regular - progressive CFR video stream?

Comment: You mean `P2LVL18_SRC20034_HRC1802_concat_wo_buffer.avi`? It's definitely progressive, and I'm seeing regular `pkt_pts_time` increments of 0.041667 when running `ffprobe` with `-show_frames`. I should add that the loop processing etc. is irrelevant to the issue; I verified that it's the same without any filtering.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this tomorrow.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks. Trac was down when I posted this; I'll see if I can reproduce it with a shorter sample that I can supply.